# ADB2C branching logic in User Journey via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, azure-ad-b2c

So, I am pretty new to ADB2C Custom Policies but here is what I have:

I have a User Journey. I have a Custom Page with a bit of JavaScript. I already solved one problem thanks to Stack Overflow but ran into another one.

When the user clicks on the login button in our customized frontend, some validation is performed. If this validation fails, we display another button which, if the user clicks it should "call" another technical profile or orchestration step in the Custom Policy.

The way how I imagine it is that this button continues my User Journey at a different predefined step, but I don't know how I would even start adding a button that does that. (I only understand that the Log In button is generated by ADB2C itself with a class "next", I presume the default behavior is that ADB2C just moves to the next orchestration step upon that button being clicked)

The reason I can't make that button just call a link is that our systems architect requested all logic being called through ADB2C, which I don't know if this is actually a good practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can:

Use a [custom error content page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-ui-customization#use-custom-page-content) and add a button out of div with id="api". Handle the click event trough JS and make it call the same (or any other) user journey appending a query param like (policy-url)?byPassStep=2. Then you can map such value to a claim type using a [claim resolver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/claim-resolver-overview#using-claim-resolvers) like this:

```xml
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="byPassStep" DefaultValue="{OAUTH-KV:byPassStep}" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
```

And then use it in a [pre-condition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/userjourneys#preconditions-examples):

```xml
<OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
  <Preconditions>
    <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
      <Value>byPassStep</Value>
      <Value>2</Value>
      <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
    </Precondition>
  </Preconditions>
</OrchestrationStep>
```